# Unfulfilled prophecies?

Tags: prophecy

My understanding is that there are numerous prophecies from the OT which have been fulfilled over the years. (Ignoring any gray areas between "prophecy" and poetic passage of scripture.)

Aside from the book of Revelation, is there an outstanding list of *pending* prophecy? I.e. things which have been foretold which haven't come to fruition?

Comment: There are several other end-times prophecies outside of Revelation.  Examples from Matthew, Isaiah, Ezekiel and Daniel come to mind immediately, and they aren't alone.  Did you mean to exclude those as well?

Comment: I was unaware of that. More details on those would be nice. I just wanted to preempt the obvious answer of "read Revelations".

Comment: All right. Just wanted to clarify that point.

Comment: Some people believe that the fall of the temple (in 70AD) fulfilled prophecies that others believe remain unfulfilled.  Because of that, interpretation of those prophecies in particular are a gray area that requires a doctrinal scope in order to interpret.  Outside of those prophecies, I believe this question can be safely answered (avoiding [this fate](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/725/why-was-my-question-closed-how-can-i-get-it-open-again)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is "yes, there are".

There are quite a few other places that prophecy about the end times, particularly in Daniel 7-12, Matthew 24, Mark 13 and Luke 21.

Matthew 24:14 specifically prophecies that the Gospel will be preached throughout the entire world prior to the end:

> And this gospel of the kingdom will be proclaimed throughout the whole
>   world as a testimony to all nations, and then the end will come. 
>   Matthew 24:14 ESV

Here are a few others:

> But understand this, that in the last days there will come times of
>   difficulty. 2For people will be lovers of self, lovers of money,
>   proud, arrogant, abusive, disobedient to their parents, ungrateful,
>   unholy, 3 heartless, unappeasable, slanderous, without self-control,
>   brutal, not loving good, 4treacherous, reckless, swollen with conceit,
>   lovers of pleasure rather than lovers of God, 5having the appearance
>   of godliness, but denying its power. Avoid such people.  2 Timothy
>   3:1-4 ESV
>
> knowing this first of all, that scoffers will come in the last days
>   with scoffing, following their own sinful desires. 4 They will say,
>   "Where is the promise of his coming? For ever since the fathers fell
>   asleep, all things are continuing as they were from the beginning of
>   creation." 5For they deliberately overlook this fact, that the heavens
>   existed long ago, and the earth was formed out of water and through
>   water by the word of God, 6and that by means of these the world that
>   then existed was deluged with water and perished. 7But by the same
>   word the heavens and earth that now exist are stored up for fire,
>   being kept until the day of judgment and destruction of the ungodly. 
>   2 Peter 3:3-7 ESV
>
> But we do not want you to be uninformed, brothers, about those who are
>   asleep, that you may not grieve as others do who have no hope. 14For
>   since we believe that Jesus died and rose again, even so, through
>   Jesus, God will bring with him those who have fallen asleep. 15For
>   this we declare to you by a word from the Lord,[d] that we who are
>   alive, who are left until the coming of the Lord, will not precede
>   those who have fallen asleep. 16For the Lord himself will descend from
>   heaven with a cry of command, with the voice of an archangel, and with
>   the sound of the trumpet of God. And the dead in Christ will rise
>   first. 17Then we who are alive, who are left, will be caught up
>   together with them in the clouds to meet the Lord in the air, and so
>   we will always be with the Lord. 18Therefore encourage one another
>   with these words.  1 Thessalonians 4:13-17 ESV
>
> This is evidence of the righteous judgment of God, that you may be
>   considered worthy of the kingdom of God, for which you are also
>   suffering— 6since indeed God considers it just to repay with
>   affliction those who afflict you, 7and to grant relief to you who are
>   afflicted as well as to us, when the Lord Jesus is revealed from
>   heaven with his mighty angels 8 in flaming fire, inflicting vengeance
>   on those who do not know God and on those who do not obey the gospel
>   of our Lord Jesus. 9They will suffer the punishment of eternal
>   destruction, away from[b] the presence of the Lord and from the glory
>   of his might, 10 when he comes on that day to be glorified in his
>   saints, and to be marveled at among all who have believed, because our
>   testimony to you was believed. 2 Thessalonians 1:5-10 ESV

Comment: I wouldn't call the 2 Timothy passage "unfulfilled."  Just watch the news; it's a perfect snapshot of our day.

Comment: I would argue that the only items here that are unfulfilled are final judgement related (which comments on the question have talked about needing to exclude) and all the others here are in active fulfillment right now. Good prophecies mind you, but not unfulfilled.

Comment: @Caleb I hear you, although we may just be seeing a shadow of those things now.  The actual fulfillment could be much more significant.

Comment: @MasonWheeler Agreed.  See note to Caleb.

Comment: @MasonWheeler. The 2 Timothy passage is a perfect snapshot of *every* day. As prophecy, it's fairly useless.

Answer (score 2):

Another example is Isaiah 61:1-2.

> 1 The Spirit of the Lord GOD is upon me,
>      because the LORD has anointed me
>   to bring good news to the poor;
>      he has sent me to bind up the brokenhearted,
>   to proclaim liberty to the captives,
>      and the opening of the prison to those who are bound;
>   2 to proclaim the year of the LORD’s favor,
>       and the day of vengeance of our God;
>      to comfort all who mourn;

In Luke 4, Jesus read this passage in the synagogue in Nazareth, but he stopped in the middle of verse 2.  He then said, "Today this Scripture has been fulfilled in your hearing." (Luke 4:21 ESV) I've heard that the reason he stopped there is that the part he read refers to his first coming, but the last part of verse 2 refers to his second coming.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Ezekiel made some wild and inaccurate prophecies:

- [Ezekiel 5:10](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Ezekiel&chapter=5&verse=10) prophesied cannibalism among the Jews because of what they had done, saying that fathers would eat sons and sons would eat fathers. He further prophesied, in 5:12:

> A third part of thee shall die with the pestilence, and with famine shall they be consumed in the midst of thee: and a third part shall fall by the sword round about thee; and I will scatter a third part into all the winds, and I will draw out a sword after them.

- [Ezekiel 26:1-15](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Ezekiel&chapter=26&verse=) said that King Nebuchadnezzar would destroy Tyre (extract):

> 11 With the hoofs of his horses shall he tread down all thy streets: he
>   shall slay thy people by the sword, and thy strong garrisons shall go
>   down to the ground.

- [Ezekiel 29:8-11](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Ezekiel&chapter=29&verse=&t=1) prophesied Egypt would be a barren wasteland:

> Therefore thus saith the Lord GOD; Behold, I will bring a sword upon thee, and cut off man and beast out of thee. And the land of Egypt shall be desolate and waste; and they shall know that I am the LORD: because he hath said, The river is mine, and I have made it. Behold, therefore I am against thee, and against thy rivers, and I will make the land of Egypt utterly waste and desolate, from the tower of Syene even unto the border of Ethiopia. **No foot of man** shall pass through it, **nor foot of beast** shall pass through it, **neither shall it be inhabited forty years**.

- This diatribe against Egypt continues through chapter 30, where (30:12) Ezekiel says the Lord God told him that he will dry up the Nile River.

Perhaps in prophesying that the Nile River would dry up, Ezekiel was relying on the slightly earlier prophet Isaiah, who had prophesied exactly the same thing in [Isaiah 19:5](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/book.php?book=Isaiah&chapter=19&verse=5):

> And the waters shall fail from the sea, and the river shall be wasted and dried up.

Comment: About the Ezekiel prophecy you mentioned, if it was written prior to the exile into Babylon, it was fulfilled then. If it was about the destruction of Jerusalem in AD 70, then it was fulfilled then. Either of those events could fulfill this prophecy, depending on when it was given to Ezekiel. Cannibalism did take place during the sieges prior to either destruction of Jerusalem. This was fulfilled.